# Probability and Combinatorics Voting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If you are a voter in a state with a million other active voters, what is the probability that your vote will be pivotal in the next election?

Assuming a given voter is equally likely to vote for either party, it seems that the answer is (1,000,000 500,000) * (1/2)^500,000 * (1/2)^500,000 and when I plug it into a calculator it gives me 7.9788E-4, which doesn't seem plausible. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Nope., [wolfram gives the same result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281000000+choose+500000%291%2F2%5E%281000000%29).  Did you expect it to be more?  Or less than this?  Why did you expect that and what makes you doubt the result you got?

Comment: Given the large amount of people, it seems that the probability of this scenario occurring would be much lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that your vote will be pivotal in deciding this kind of perfect election can be calculated as the probability that 500,000 people will vote for one candidate and 5000,000 people will vote for the second candidate. Just as you calculated, this probability will be ${1,000,000 \choose 500,000} \times (\frac{1}{2})^{1000000}=7.9788... \times 10^{-4}.$ This probability is somewhere around one in a thousand. You might have been expecting a probability closer to one in a million, but the probability is as high as it is because of the law of large numbers. The great majority of the time the final count for each side will fall somewhere in between $500,000\pm 1000.$ In other words, the race will tend to be fairly close, so there is a relatively high probability that your vote (and everyone else's) will sway the election.

Comment: It's worth mentioning where the $\pm 1000$ comes from.  That is $\pm 2\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, noting that the standard deviation for a binomial distribution is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and the mean is $np$.

Comment: But but but, you should also take into account that the "pivotal" voter must be the last one to vote, otherwise the term "pivotal" is meaningless. Now I don't know how voting orders are decided, but being the last voter already sounds like one in a million to me!

Comment: @WhatsUp I would disagree with that. I think you can consider each vote to have been pivotal in a scenario where every vote for the winning candidate was necessary for their election.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't call it "the deciding vote", since it's rather a "pivotal situation" than a "pivotal vote". There are $500001$ pivotal votes...